# UWP PDFTron pdf viewer next previous button modification

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal, pdftron

In PDFTron there is a next and previous buttons appear in the document viewer. (UWP app). I have a requirement to place these buttons to the bottom of the screen and also scale it a bit. Does anyone have any idea how to do that? (It looks like the buttons appear from the OS and not from the app)

```
<Border x:Name="PDFViewCtrlBorder">
     <Grid>
         <Border Child="{Binding PDFViewCtrl}" />
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: The control looks UWP [FlipView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview?view=winrt-22000), you could custom it's style to place next and previous buttons bottom.

Comment: Hi, it's not a FlipView. I have updated the question to have the XAML code for the viewer.

Comment: What's `PDFViewCtrl`, do you have it's xaml code ?

Comment: If the next and previous button are part of PDFViewCtrl, you need check the default style of PDFViewCtrl and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those buttons are part of the internal `FlipView` control inside the `PDFViewCtrl`.

There is no option to modify the style but you can hide those buttons and create your own custom button controls on top (overlay) of the PDFViewCtrl.

To hide the FlipView buttons you can call

`PDFViewCtrl.PreviousAndNextButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`

Also, make sure to update to the latest PDFTron's UWP SDK version to access the latest APIs.